# RestTemplate and acessing json

Tags: json, spring, jackson, resttemplate

I have seen the responses from many other posts but would like to understand if there is a better way to do the same thing.

Requirement:-
I am using restTemplate to talk to web service which returns JSON output which is dynamic. As a consumer I don't want to access all fields but is interested in few of them. I am using Spring framework with Jackson parser and found the way of accessing it

```
     String  response = restTemplate.getForObject(targetUrl, String.class);
     System.out.println(response);
     ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
     JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readValue(response, JsonNode.class);
     JsonNode uri = rootNode.get("uri");
     System.out.println(uri.asText());
```

Do you know any better way to do it? Mapping to java Object is something that I dont want to do as the json output is not in my control

Comment: Your approach looks good. Note that just do restTemplate.getForObject(targetUrl, JsonNode.class) assuming that your restTemplate is configured to work with Jackson.

Comment: "restTemplate is configured to work with Jackson" Can you please clarify this?

Comment: You can set an HttpMessageCoverter for your rest template which will covert JSON to java objects. Take a look at the example code this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355450/spring-resttemplate-with-jackson-as-httpmessageconverter-and-joda-datetime-prope

Comment: Isnt that is there when you create RestTemplate Object?. I saw it has list of converters already set

Comment: Using `ObjectMapper` is redundant here. As Alexey said you can just use `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode` as the second argument for the `restTemplate.getForObject()` method.

Answer (score 5):

If your `RestTemplate` is configured with the **default** `HttpMessageConverters`, which is provided by `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`, you may directly get a `JsonNode` from `restTemplate.getForObject`.

For example,

```
ArrayNode resources = restTemplate.getForObject("/resources", ArrayNode.class);
```

Or,

```
ObjectNode resource = restTemplate.getForObject("/resources/123", ObjectNode.class);
```

Note that `ArrayNode` and `ObjectNode` are sub-classes of `JsonNode`.