# Get specefic value from ResponseEntity Resttemplate

Tags: java, spring, api

I have this call I am making with

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = new RestTemplate().exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);
        String json = response.getBody();
```

This returns the following json

```
{
  "id": "T-5IB4VHCDNJs9AAQr31zQlKRjfA0WEnMe1pLrp5irXRRnw",
  "accountId": "qi0oxfBt0C968y6ku1rsxWeqSDolBFWYRlLgxVTo5FHVIeQ",
  "puuid": "HDzjdaStxhHcceGGd8qJcc4Vw45FOlOQ1PNXKQ0h9_iqfwHP3oI0spl1bLUOw_7_J49vzaIKylv5Vg",
  "name": "King yibz",
  "profileIconId": 4072,
  "revisionDate": 1639613941000,
  "summonerLevel": 221
}
```

what is the best way to just return the summonerLevel value?

Answer (score 2):

(*If we don't want to map the complete response structure*,) See here: [RestTemplate and acessing json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24713375/592355)

> If your `RestTemplate` is configured with the default HttpMessageConverters, which is provided by <s>`Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`</s>, you may directly get a `JsonNode` from `restTemplate.getForObject` (/getForEntity/exchange/put/post/patch/...).

Nowadays it would be the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` [[ref](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#rest-message-conversion)], but we still can obtain a [(`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.`)`JsonNode`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.13/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) like:

```java
ResponseEntity<JsonNode> response = new RestTemplate().exchange(
  url, 
  HttpMethod.GET, 
  request, // ??
  JsonNode.class
); // in a GET request parameters are normally in URL!, so we could:
// ResponseEntity<JsonNode> resultEnt = restTemplate.getForEntity(url+queryString, JsonNode.class);
// Or if we don't need the ResponseEntity at all (status, header, ...), just:
// JsonNode resultObj = restTemplate.getForObject(url + query, JsonNode.class);
JsonNode json = response.getBody();
```

We can then extract "summonerLevel" like:

```java
int summonerLevel = json.findValue("summonerLevel").asInt(); // (more) exceptions possible!
```

---

Please also keep in mind:

> As of (spring(-web)) 5.0 the `RestTemplate` is in *maintenance mode*, with only minor requests for changes and bugs to be accepted going forward. Please, consider using the [`WebClient`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-client) which offers a more modern API and supports sync, async, and streaming scenarios.

Refs:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#webmvc-resttemplate
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#rest-resttemplate
- https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind