# Parsing nested elements with Spring Boot RestTemplate gives JSON parse error

Tags: java, xml, spring, rest

I want to consume a REST interface that gives the following output (to be precise, I want to retrieve the list of TAF elements):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XML-Schema-instance" version="1.2" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://aviationweather.gov/adds/schema/taf1_2.xsd">
  <request_index>32084191</request_index>
  <data_source name="tafs" />
  <request type="retrieve" />
  <errors />
  <warnings />
  <time_taken_ms>13</time_taken_ms>
  <data num_results="4">
    <TAF>
      <raw_text>TAF EPGD 171130Z 1712/1812 25008KT CAVOK PROB40 1718/1806 1500 BR BKN005</raw_text>
      <station_id>EPGD</station_id>
      <issue_time>2017-10-17T11:30:00Z</issue_time>
      <bulletin_time>2017-10-17T11:00:00Z</bulletin_time>
      <valid_time_from>2017-10-17T12:00:00Z</valid_time_from>
      <valid_time_to>2017-10-18T12:00:00Z</valid_time_to>
      <latitude>54.37</latitude>
      <longitude>18.47</longitude>
      <elevation_m>138.0</elevation_m>
      <forecast>
        <fcst_time_from>2017-10-17T12:00:00Z</fcst_time_from>
        <fcst_time_to>2017-10-18T12:00:00Z</fcst_time_to>
        <wind_dir_degrees>250</wind_dir_degrees>
        <wind_speed_kt>8</wind_speed_kt>
        <visibility_statute_mi>6.21</visibility_statute_mi>
        <wx_string>NSW</wx_string>
        <sky_condition sky_cover="NSC" />
      </forecast>
      <forecast>
        <fcst_time_from>2017-10-17T18:00:00Z</fcst_time_from>
        <fcst_time_to>2017-10-18T06:00:00Z</fcst_time_to>
        <change_indicator>PROB</change_indicator>
        <probability>40</probability>
        <visibility_statute_mi>0.93</visibility_statute_mi>
        <wx_string>BR</wx_string>
        <sky_condition sky_cover="BKN" cloud_base_ft_agl="500" />
      </forecast>
    </TAF>
    <TAF>
      <raw_text>TAF EPGD 170530Z 1706/1806 22010KT 0300 FG BKN002 BECMG 1707/1709 CAVOK</raw_text>
      <station_id>EPGD</station_id>
      <issue_time>2017-10-17T05:30:00Z</issue_time>
      <bulletin_time>2017-10-17T05:00:00Z</bulletin_time>
      <valid_time_from>2017-10-17T06:00:00Z</valid_time_from>
      <valid_time_to>2017-10-18T06:00:00Z</valid_time_to>
      <latitude>54.37</latitude>
      <longitude>18.47</longitude>
      <elevation_m>138.0</elevation_m>
      <forecast>
        <fcst_time_from>2017-10-17T06:00:00Z</fcst_time_from>
        <fcst_time_to>2017-10-17T07:00:00Z</fcst_time_to>
        <wind_dir_degrees>220</wind_dir_degrees>
        <wind_speed_kt>10</wind_speed_kt>
        <visibility_statute_mi>0.19</visibility_statute_mi>
        <wx_string>FG</wx_string>
        <sky_condition sky_cover="BKN" cloud_base_ft_agl="200" />
      </forecast>
      <forecast>
        <fcst_time_from>2017-10-17T07:00:00Z</fcst_time_from>
        <fcst_time_to>2017-10-18T06:00:00Z</fcst_time_to>
        <change_indicator>BECMG</change_indicator>
        <time_becoming>2017-10-17T09:00:00Z</time_becoming>
        <wind_dir_degrees>220</wind_dir_degrees>
        <wind_speed_kt>10</wind_speed_kt>
        <visibility_statute_mi>6.21</visibility_statute_mi>
        <wx_string>NSW</wx_string>
        <sky_condition sky_cover="NSC" />
      </forecast>
    </TAF>
    <TAF>
      <raw_text>TAF EPGD 162330Z 1700/1724 24006KT 7000 SCT012 TEMPO 1700/1708 BKN005 PROB40 1702/1707 1000 BR OVC002</raw_text>
      <station_id>EPGD</station_id>
      <issue_time>2017-10-16T23:30:00Z</issue_time>
      <bulletin_time>2017-10-16T23:00:00Z</bulletin_time>
      <valid_time_from>2017-10-17T00:00:00Z</valid_time_from>
      <valid_time_to>2017-10-18T00:00:00Z</valid_time_to>
      <latitude>54.37</latitude>
      <longitude>18.47</longitude>
      <elevation_m>138.0</elevation_m>
      <forecast>
        <fcst_time_from>2017-10-17T00:00:00Z</fcst_time_from>
        <fcst_time_to>2017-10-17T08:00:00Z</fcst_time_to>
        <change_indicator>TEMPO</change_indicator>
        <sky_condition sky_cover="BKN" cloud_base_ft_agl="500" />
      </forecast>
      <forecast>
        <fcst_time_from>2017-10-17T00:00:00Z</fcst_time_from>
        <fcst_time_to>2017-10-18T00:00:00Z</fcst_time_to>
        <wind_dir_degrees>240</wind_dir_degrees>
        <wind_speed_kt>6</wind_speed_kt>
        <visibility_statute_mi>4.35</visibility_statute_mi>
        <sky_condition sky_cover="SCT" cloud_base_ft_agl="1200" />
      </forecast>
      <forecast>
        <fcst_time_from>2017-10-17T02:00:00Z</fcst_time_from>
        <fcst_time_to>2017-10-17T07:00:00Z</fcst_time_to>
        <change_indicator>PROB</change_indicator>
        <probability>40</probability>
        <visibility_statute_mi>0.62</visibility_statute_mi>
        <wx_string>BR</wx_string>
        <sky_condition sky_cover="OVC" cloud_base_ft_agl="200" />
      </forecast>
    </TAF>
    <TAF>
      <raw_text>TAF EPGD 161730Z 1618/1718 24006KT CAVOK BECMG 1618/1620 BKN013 TEMPO 1621/1708 BKN005 PROB40 1700/1707 2000 BR OVC002 BECMG 1709/1711 SCT030</raw_text>
      <station_id>EPGD</station_id>
      <issue_time>2017-10-16T17:30:00Z</issue_time>
      <bulletin_time>2017-10-16T17:00:00Z</bulletin_time>
      <valid_time_from>2017-10-16T18:00:00Z</valid_time_from>
      <valid_time_to>2017-10-17T18:00:00Z</valid_time_to>
      <latitude>54.37</latitude>
      <longitude>18.47</longitude>
      <elevation_m>138.0</elevation_m>
      <forecast>
        <fcst_time_from>2017-10-16T18:00:00Z</fcst_time_from>
        <fcst_time_to>2017-10-17T18:00:00Z</fcst_time_to>
        <wind_dir_degrees>240</wind_dir_degrees>
        <wind_speed_kt>6</wind_speed_kt>
        <visibility_statute_mi>6.21</visibility_statute_mi>
        <wx_string>NSW</wx_string>
        <sky_condition sky_cover="NSC" />
      </forecast>
      <forecast>
        <fcst_time_from>2017-10-16T18:00:00Z</fcst_time_from>
        <fcst_time_to>2017-10-17T09:00:00Z</fcst_time_to>
        <change_indicator>BECMG</change_indicator>
        <time_becoming>2017-10-16T20:00:00Z</time_becoming>
        <wind_dir_degrees>240</wind_dir_degrees>
        <wind_speed_kt>6</wind_speed_kt>
        <visibility_statute_mi>6.21</visibility_statute_mi>
        <wx_string>NSW</wx_string>
        <sky_condition sky_cover="BKN" cloud_base_ft_agl="1300" />
      </forecast>
      <forecast>
        <fcst_time_from>2017-10-16T21:00:00Z</fcst_time_from>
        <fcst_time_to>2017-10-17T08:00:00Z</fcst_time_to>
        <change_indicator>TEMPO</change_indicator>
        <sky_condition sky_cover="BKN" cloud_base_ft_agl="500" />
      </forecast>
      <forecast>
        <fcst_time_from>2017-10-17T00:00:00Z</fcst_time_from>
        <fcst_time_to>2017-10-17T07:00:00Z</fcst_time_to>
        <change_indicator>PROB</change_indicator>
        <probability>40</probability>
        <visibility_statute_mi>1.24</visibility_statute_mi>
        <wx_string>BR</wx_string>
        <sky_condition sky_cover="OVC" cloud_base_ft_agl="200" />
      </forecast>
      <forecast>
        <fcst_time_from>2017-10-17T09:00:00Z</fcst_time_from>
        <fcst_time_to>2017-10-17T18:00:00Z</fcst_time_to>
        <change_indicator>BECMG</change_indicator>
        <time_becoming>2017-10-17T11:00:00Z</time_becoming>
        <wind_dir_degrees>240</wind_dir_degrees>
        <wind_speed_kt>6</wind_speed_kt>
        <visibility_statute_mi>6.21</visibility_statute_mi>
        <wx_string>NSW</wx_string>
        <sky_condition sky_cover="SCT" cloud_base_ft_agl="3000" />
      </forecast>
    </TAF>
  </data>
</response>
```

My POJO Classes look like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "response")
public class Response {
    @XmlElement private List<Taf> data; // I don't need any other contents of this element

    public List<Taf> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<Taf> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "TAF")
public class Taf {
    @XmlElement(name = "raw_text") private String raw_text;
    @XmlElement(name = "station_id") private String station_id; // ICAO
    @XmlElement(name = "issue_time") private Date issue_time;
    @XmlElement(name = "bulletin_time") private Date bulletin_time;
    @XmlElement(name = "valid_time_from") private Date valid_time_from;
    @XmlElement(name = "valid_time_to") private Date valid_time_to;
    @XmlElement(name = "remarks") private String remarks;
    @XmlElement(name = "latitude") private Double latitude;
    @XmlElement(name = "longitude") private Double longitude;
    @XmlElement(name = "elevation_m") private Double elevation_m;
    @XmlElement(name = "forecast", type = Forecast.class) private List<Forecast> forecast;
    // getters and setters
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "forecast")
public class Forecast {
    @XmlElement(name = "fcst_time_from") private Date fcst_time_from;
    @XmlElement(name = "fcst_time_to") private Date fcst_time_to;
    @XmlElement(name = "wind_dir_degrees") private Integer wind_dir_degrees;
    @XmlElement(name = "wind_speed_kt") private Integer wind_speed_kt;
    @XmlElement(name = "visibility_statute_mi") private Double visibility_statute_mi;
    @XmlElement(name = "wx_string") private String wx_string;
    @XmlElement(name = "sky_condition", type = SkyCondition.class) private List<SkyCondition> sky_condition;
    // getters and setters
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "sky_condition")
public class SkyCondition {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "sky_cover") private String sky_cover;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "cloud_base_ft_agl") private Integer cloud_base_ft_agl;
    // getters and setters
}
```

Now my service has a simple method:

```
public List<Taf> getTafsForICAO(String icao) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    Response resp = restTemplate.getForObject(tafUrl+icao, Response.class);
    return resp.getData();
}
```

If I ignore the nested `forecast` elements everything parses correctly. But I need those nested elements, and If I run everything as it is, I get the following exception:

```
Failed to read HTTP message:
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error:
Can not construct instance of airports.models.taf.Forecast:
no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2017-10-17T12:00:00Z'); nested exception is 
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of airports.models.taf.Forecast: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2017-10-17T12:00:00Z')
at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@4c723aba; line: 21, column: 45] (through reference chain: airports.models.taf.Response["data"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->airports.models.taf.Taf["forecast"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

It looks like the parser saw the first subelement of `forecast`, which is `fcst_time_from` took its contents and tried to deserialize the date into `Forecast` object. I don't know why. Maybe I'm missing something simple? Thanks in advance for any help.

## UPDATE

I am a bit closer to the problem. The nested `TAF` elements are parsed properly inside `response` element because they are wrapped in `data` element. Unfortunately, there is no wrapping element for list of `forecast` tags inside `TAF`. I created a constructor with String argument for `Forecast` class and now it parses the embedded elements (fcst_time_from, fcst_time_to and so on) as `Forcast` objects. Is there a way to declare that this inner list has no wrapping element?

## UPDATE 2

After some tests I figured that the problewm is strictly related to parsing unwrapped lists of elements. I don't know why, but if I declare my `Result` class like this, instead of the declaration shown higher:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "response")
public class Response {
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "data")
    @XmlElement(name = "TAF")
    private List<Taf> tafs;

    public List<Taf> getTafs() {
        return tafs;
    }

    public void setTafs(List<Taf> tafs) {
        this.tafs = tafs;
    }
}
```

It does not work. No TAF elements are parsed. It seems like the parser is forcing all the lists to be wrapped. Unfortunately I get unwrapped `forecast` lists in the REST output. How can I deal with this? I saw a parameter for `@Element(inline = true)` annotation, but `@XmlElement` doesn't have such a thing. Can I somehow force unwrapped lists in the RestTemplate itself?

Comment: Please fix the primary problem first, then we can see... The primary problem is: Your RestTemplate cannot parse/deserialize '2017-10-17T12:00:00Z' as a 'java.utill.Date'! For the solution refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21355450/592355 (`ObjectMapper.setDateFormat()`!)

Comment: @xerx593 No, it's not that. It parses '2017-10-17T12:00:00Z' as a 'java.utill.Date' with no problem. When I comment out the List<Forecast> forecast the Taf objects are parsed properly (and they contain Date fields). This  error says that it tries do deserialize this date string into Forecast object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## OMG

Two days of struggle to find out I need one line to solve this. So... it seems all those `@XmlElement` annotations are useless from the parser's perspective. They are used only when I want to output the objects back as a REST service. In order to tell anything to parser I needed to use `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper` annotation. The exact solution is:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "TAF")
public class Taf {
    @XmlElement(name = "raw_text") private String raw_text;
    @XmlElement(name = "station_id") private String station_id; // ICAO
    @XmlElement(name = "issue_time") private Date issue_time;
    @XmlElement(name = "bulletin_time") private Date bulletin_time;
    @XmlElement(name = "valid_time_from") private Date valid_time_from;
    @XmlElement(name = "valid_time_to") private Date valid_time_to;
    @XmlElement(name = "remarks") private String remarks;
    @XmlElement(name = "latitude") private Double latitude;
    @XmlElement(name = "longitude") private Double longitude;
    @XmlElement(name = "elevation_m") private Double elevation_m;
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @XmlElement(name = "forecast") private List<Forecast> forecast;
    // getters and setters
}
```

and

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "forecast")
public class Forecast {
    @XmlElement(name = "fcst_time_from") private Date fcst_time_from;
    @XmlElement(name = "fcst_time_to") private Date fcst_time_to;
    @XmlElement(name = "wind_dir_degrees") private Integer wind_dir_degrees;
    @XmlElement(name = "wind_speed_kt") private Integer wind_speed_kt;
    @XmlElement(name = "visibility_statute_mi") private Double visibility_statute_mi;
    @XmlElement(name = "ex_string") private String wx_string;
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @XmlElement(name = "sky_condition") private List<SkyCondition> sky_condition;
    // getters and setters
}
```

That's it.